# BigQuery fetching this week and last week data

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have a query:

```
SELECT ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium, SUM(ga_sessionDuration)/SUM(ga_sessions) as avg_sessionDuration 

FROM database.table 

group by ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium
```

.

How do I select *last week* and *this week's* data from `BigQuery` if I have a `DATE` column which looks like this `2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DATE_TRUNC is a useful function to get the beginning of the week and DATE_SUB gets you to last week

[DATE_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_trunc)

[DATE_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_sub)

```
SELECT if(date(date) >= DATE_TRUNC(current_date(), WEEK(MONDAY)),"This Week","Last Week") weekPeriod, 
 ga_channelGrouping, 
 ga_sourceMedium, 
 SUM(ga_sessionDuration)/SUM(ga_sessions) as avg_sessionDuration 

FROM database.table 
WHERE date(date) >= DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(current_date(), WEEK(MONDAY)), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
group by weekPeriod, ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium
```

If your week starts on a Sunday, simply change **WEEK(MONDAY)** to **WEEK(SUNDAY)**